# Need to add a Independent 404 page in Angular without Header or Footer

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, angular-router

I have created a Angular application and for that, If the user points to an unknown URL, it should step into a 404 page showing a friendly message to redirect to Home.
 Now I created a component showing this 404. Now the problem is , it shows with header and footer. In this case I don't want the header & footer to be displayed 
[The page right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxOOQ.png)
I need to display the 404 without the header and footer. Is there any simple way to achieve it. Thanks in Advance.

Index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="!webLoading">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="minhgt-router-outlet">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
<div class='modal d-flex carousel' *ngIf="webLoading">
    <p-progressSpinner [style]="{width: '50px', height: '50px'}" 
    strokeWidth="4" fill="#ffffff" animationDuration=".8s"></p-progressSpinner>
</div>
```

not-found.component.html

```
<div class="notfound">
        <div class="notfound-404">
            <h3>Oops! Page not found</h3>
            <h1>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>0</span>
                <span>4</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <h2>we are sorry, but the page you requested was not found</h2>
</div>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: BodyContentComponent
  },
{ 
    path: "**", 
    component: NotFoundComponent
   }
];
```

Comment: what's webLoading ?

Comment: @A.khalifa That is just spinner to show until we get API response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AppComponent, you can subscribe to router events and check for the current URL, and add a condition based on that in template file.

```
url: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map((e: NavigationEnd) => this.url = e.urlAfterRedirects)
  ).subscribe();
}
```

And then, in your template,

```
<ng-container *ngIf="url !== '/404url'"> <app-header></app-header></ng-container>
```

Also, for this to work, you should have a specific route for 404 page, and redirect all wild card routes to that page.

```
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: '404PageRoute',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},  {
  path: '404PageRoute',
  component: NotFountcomponent
}
```

Comment: I followed the steps from in here. Whenever the page is **404PageRoute** it seems to work, Other routes like if it is a random route E.g. **asds**, it redirects to **404PageRoute** but displays with header and footer. Sorry if I didn't capture anything from your answer.

Comment: You can change this.url = e.url to -> this.url = e.urlAfterRedirects

Answer (score 4):

In your css of not-found.component add

```
.hasDisplay {
  display: none;
}
```

`hasDisplay` class must be in your div of Header and Footer

and add

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Hope useful